# How to implement Live Streaming on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, live-streaming

I want to implement Audio Live Streaming on Windows Phone. most of them told Windows Phone 7 sdk does not support Streaming. so I upgrade and install Windows Phone 7.1.

Which class i want to use to implement Live Streaming?????

Please give some guidelines and materials to do this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format is the audio you wish to stream?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using IIS 7.X for the streaming portion. The following link shows how you can build the client app for Windows Phone 7:
http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=2020

The sample requires the IIS Smooth Streaming Client (1.1), Silverlight 4, and the Visual Studio Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools.