# Windows phone based live video streaming Application

Tags: windows-phone-7, video-streaming, iis-7.5, live-streaming, videochat

i am hoping to develop a live video streaming app for windows phone.

I want to know what protocols and libraries support are provided for windows phone?
I want to implement a sort of Video chat application..

An example for Android and Iphone:
http://techcrunch.com/2010/03/24/knocking-live-video-now-lets-you-stream-between-android-and-iphone-devices/

Comment: Yes.. i want to give live video streaming between any two windows phone devices..

Comment: As in Android RTMP protocol is used..what about windows phone 7?

Comment: Are you attempting to do a live stream from a server to WP7 or to have a video chat application? I was confused by the "iis-7.5" tag on the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Live Streaming on Windows Phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490542/how-to-implement-live-streaming-on-windows-phone)

Answer (score 1):

As you have an IIS-7.5 tag I am going to assume you are talking about streaming from a server to multiple WP7 devices. In which case you may want to consider using IIS 7.X for the streaming portion. The following link shows how you can build the client app for Windows Phone 7: http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=2020

The sample requires the IIS Smooth Streaming Client (1.1), Silverlight 4, and the Visual Studio Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools.

Comment: I want to implement a sort of Video chat application, is this information can be used to make such an app?
An example:
http://techcrunch.com/2010/03/24/knocking-live-video-now-lets-you-stream-between-android-and-iphone-devices/

Answer (score 0):

At the moment live streaming is *possible* but it ill not be allowed on AppHub for distribution. This is because you have to *hack* the dll's. This is because when you switch from your app to the camera it physically goes to the camera mode. To live stream you have to override this.

[Her is the Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/151485/Hacking-the-WP7-Camera-The-basics)

Comment: LOVE getting downvoted for having the correct answer. Thanks @mekici

Comment: I want to implement a sort of Video chat application..

An example for Android and Iphone: http://techcrunch.com/2010/03/24/knocking-live-video-now-lets-you-stream-between-android-and-iphone-devices/

Comment: You can do that with that example BUT AppHub wont certify your app. It is NOT allowed on WP7 at the moment.